# Translating vbscript string to c# string

Tags: c#, vb.net, vbscript

Ok I have a vbscript string in a wsf file as below:

```
 Dim strTransData = "1,1,2,123457,1,20051012093000" & vbCrLf & _
                    "2,1" & vbCrLf & _
                    "2,2" & vbCrLf & _
                    "2,3" & vbCrLf & _
                    "3,""5449000000996"",0,3,39" & vbCrLf & _
                    "3,"""",100,1,500" & vbCrLf & _
                    "4,0,200,"""""
```

What I need to do is convert this string to a c# string, I understand that a vbscript  **&** translates to a **+** in c# string concatentation but what does **vbCrLf** and **_** translate to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vbCrLf` is a synonym for a line-end (`Environment.NewLine`).

`_` (underscore) allows multiple line statements within VB.

Also, double-double-quotes `""` are the VB way of escaping the quotes.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can use a verbatim string literal, in which case your quote encoding would remain the same and your newlines are actual newlines:

```
string transData = @"1,1,2,123457,1,20051012093000
2,1
2,2
2,3
3,""5449000000996"",0,3,39
3,"""",100,1,500
4,0,200,""""";
```

Comment: +1, but be careful letting extra whitespace slip in this way.

Answer (score 2):

C# uses:

- "+" for concatenation
- No line-continuation characters (the "_" in VB.NET)
- \" for a literal quote (rather than "" like VB.NET)
- \r\n for a CR and LF (literally, inside a string)
- Alternately, you can use Environment.NewLine

So:

```
 string strTransData = "1,1,2,123457,1,20051012093000" + "\r\n" + 
     "2,1" + "\r\n" + 
     "2,2" + "\r\n" + 
     "2,3" + "\r\n" + 
     "3,\"5449000000996\",0,3,39" + "\r\n" + 
     "3,\"\",100,1,500" + "\r\n" + 
     "4,0,200,\"\"";
```

Comment: Actually, it's probably easier to translate just using unescapted strings (precede the inital quote for the literal with a "@" character ) and you should avoid \n and \r in favor or Environment.Newline

Comment: Why can't I type "unescaped" today? I had the same typo in my own answer :(

Answer (score 2):

```
string TransData = new StringBuilder("1,1,2,123457,1,20051012093000",100).AppendLine("")
         .AppendLine("2,1")
         .AppendLine("2,2")
         .AppendLine("2,3")
         .AppendLine(@"3,""5449000000996"",0,3,39")
         .AppendLine(@"3,"""",100,1,500")
         .Append(@"4,0,200,""""")
         .ToString();
```

This will avoid *any* string concatenation (which can be slow in .Net) and allocates a buffer up front that can hold the entire result string.  Note the use of un-escaped strings to make converting the escaped quotes easier.

Comment: If the string concatenation was fast enough in the original VBScript, it probably is in .Net! I suppose the VBScript may have been a prototype though.

Comment: I'm not saying the concatentation would be a bottleneck, but why make it slower than it needs to be?

Comment: Using StringBuilder for this example is slower than richardtallent's solution since his will be joined into a single string at compile-time. Using Environment.NewLine, however, would be slower since it needs to be resolved at runtime. Even so, I'd probably recommend String.Concat over a StringBuilder for that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

```
Environment.NewLine
```

Or use something like http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/ if you have lots to convert.

EDIT: That link appears dead for now.. there are other free online converters. But for something so simple as a string like this; you can do it manually ;)